pyQGIS - using QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat() to export to MapInfo file
Newbie to pyQGIS and QGIS in General
Looking to import WKT file (csv) and then export to MapInfo.
Able to import the CSV into a temp layer.
Having issues with parameters for QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat and looking for anyone with examples to assist.  Or should I be using QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer instead ?
Code todate for wkt import
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter
import urllib.parse
import pathlib

#---  2 Turn of the CRS dialog box
s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour")
s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" )

#--- 3 Set file name here
InFlnm='/All Jobs LWKT'
FlnmExt='.csv'

#--- 4  Set pathname here
InDrPth="D://_GIS//04_PROJECTS//BAU Control//Data Files"

#--- 5 Build file name an path for uri
InFlPth=InDrPth+InFlnm+FlnmExt
abspath = os.path.abspath(InFlPth)
params = {'type': 'csv',
          'delimiter':',',
          'crs': 'EPSG:28354',
          'wktField': 'wkt',
          'geomType': 'line'}

#---  6 Set import Sting here note only need to set x and y other come for free

uri = "%s?%s" %(pathlib.Path(abspath).as_uri(), urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))
print (uri)
#--- 7 Load point layer
bh = QgsVectorLayer(uri, InFlnm, "delimitedtext")

#--- 8 Confirm something is loaded and valid
#print (bh.isValid())

#--- 10 Display the layer into QGIS (but it asks for CRS before displaying_
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(bh)

#--- 11 turn CRS dialog box back on again
s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation )


#QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "OutFnm", "UTF-8", None, "MapInfo File")

